# cordova emulate android stuck in loading forever in CMD

Tags: android, cordova, cmd

*The info I suppose would be useful to you:*

cordova its version command tells me I have the following version: 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)

The emulator I use: Pixel 2 API_29

I start my emulator through the AVD manager (android studio)

How I start the emulator: cordova emulate android

So, when I use CMD to start my application, it basically ends up with loading dots. 
Sometimes the launch etc. is successful, but sometimes, out of nowhere, it keeps on loading, but the launch is never successful.
The build is: success, the launch and deployment however fails.
The loading looks like this in cmd:

```
...................................................
```

but it never starts the application.

To give you an idea of how it looks:

```
(...) //above this line there is info about the build etc.
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 8s
42 actionable tasks: 42 up-to-date
Built the following apk(s):
    C:\Users\gamek\hexadecimal\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\gamek\AppData\Local\Android\sdk (DEPRECATED)
..............................................................................
```

*The desired behavior I am looking for:*

Not have to live in fear whether the application will start in the emulator or not.
I want the application to start in the emulator when I run the command:

cordova emulate android

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

- Check that the emulator memory requirements are not too excessive for your system's resources (lower RAM allocated for example, but not below 1024 MB)
- Start the emulator manually immediately after booting
- Don't close the emulator anymore, leave it running so you can deploy without issues

[More Android emulator tips here](https://www.andreszsogon.com/using-android-8-and-9-emulators-without-android-studio/), make sure you have installed *Intel HAXM* if you have an **Intel** processor, or enabled *Windows Hypervisor Platform* in Windows Features if you have **AMD**.

Comment: To make an add on to your post: When it goes into a loading state you can also go in the ADV manager, click on the arrow in the section 'actions' and press 'wipe data'. Start CMD again and use the command cordova emulate android. It has been consistent in actually loading the apk and launching it successfully.